# integral by part with distribution function.

Tags: integration

I have a solution for my homework and I was not sure how the integral by part was implemented in the following equations... Could anyone give explanation to hidden steps that lead to the equations below? thank you!
[image: Equations]

Comment: Please tell us what you did and why you are confused. You will see that people will put effort into their response if you put effort into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From differential you know that for every two differentiable functions $u$ and $v$ :
$$d(uv)=du.v+dv.u$$
or
$$udv=d(uv)-vdu$$
integration gives
\begin{align}
\int udv
&=\int d(uv)-\int vdu\\
&=uv-\int vdu
\end{align}
this formula uses in integration by parts. Here we have $\displaystyle H(p)=\int_{\theta}^{r^{-1}(p)}\theta d\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}$ and then let  $u=\theta$, $dv=d\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}$ or $v=\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}$ hence
\begin{align}
\int udv
&=\int d(uv)-\int vdu\\
\int_{\theta}^{r^{-1}(p)}\theta d\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}
&=\theta~\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}-\int \dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))} d\theta
\end{align}
set upper and lower bounds then
\begin{align}
\int_{\theta}^{r^{-1}(p)}\theta d\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}
&=\theta~\dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))}\Big|_{\theta}^{r^{-1}(p)}-\int_{\theta}^{r^{-1}(p)} \dfrac{F(\theta)}{F(r^{-1}(p))} d\theta
\end{align}